# How to create multiple HTML tables of data inside 1 email

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to send 2 different tables inside of 1 email. I want one table to establish data concerning data stored in 1 database and the other table for a second database of information. I can produce 1 email simply enough but i cannot understand how to set a second table with a completely different query and data in the same email.

here is what i am currently working with:

```
USE MY DATABASE

DECLARE 
@tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX)




SET @tableHTML =
N'<H1>Lacrosse Inquiries</H1>' +
N'<table border="1" style="text-align: middle;" width:100% height:20px style="cell"      cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">' +
N'<tr><th>FIRST NAME</th><th>LAST NAME</th><th>Entry Term</th></th><th>Market     Segment</th><th>State</th><th>Home Number</th><th>Cell Phone</th>'+
CAST ( ( SELECT td =  INQUIRY.F_NAME      , ''
            , td = INQUIRY.L_NAME    , ''
            , td = INQUIRY.ENTRY_TERM   , ''
            , td = INQUIRY.MARKET_SEG   , ''
            , td = EWADDRESS.STATE   , ''
            , td = EWADDRESS.HOME_PHONE   , ''
            , td = EWADDRESS.WORK_PHONE   , ''





from  EWSTUDENT AS INQUIRY inner join EWMULTI1M as sport on     sport.EWSTUID=INQUIRY.EWSTUID left JOIN EWADDRESS ON EWADDRESS.EWSTUID=INQUIRY.EWSTUID LEFT     JOIN ESTUDENT ON ESTUDENT.EWSTUID=INQUIRY.EWSTUID
where VCODETYPE = 'EACTIV1M' AND VCODE ='CLAX' AND INQUIRY.GENDER = 'F' AND STUD_TYPE     ='P' and (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), sport.CREATE_DT, 112) = CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112))
order by INQUIRY.L_NAME




         FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>' ;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name= 'Jordan.Sorensen',
        @recipients = 'Jordan.sorensen@svu.edu',
        @from_address = 'Jordan.Sorensen@svu.edu',
        @body = @tableHTML,
        @execute_query_database= 'MY DATABASE',
        @subject ='Womens Lacrosse Inquiries',
        @body_format= 'HTML'

GO
```

ANY SUGGESTIONS ON HOW TO CREATE TWO DIFFERENT TABLES WITH TWO COMPLETELY DIFFERENT SETS OF DATA IN ONE EMAIL?

Answer (score 0):

```
         FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>'          --<-- This is where you 1st query ends add a couple of line breaks
  + N'<br/><br/>'       -- and add you second table just like you have done before

  + N'<table border="1" style="text-align: middle;" width:100% height:20px style="cell" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">' 
  + N'<tr><th>FIRST NAME</th><th>LAST NAME</th><th>Entry Term</th></th><th>Market Segment</th><th>State</th><th>Home Number</th><th>Cell Phone</th>'
  + CAST ( (/*Your Select just like you have done for 1st table*/) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
  + N'</table>'
```

Obviously `HTML` generated from both sql queries are concatenated and set the value to variable `@tableHTML`, the rest of the stuff remains the same passing parameters to your procedure and etc etc.